# qt build application for 32 bits

Tags: qt

i am not developer, i have application source code developed in qt for 64 bit, and i need to compile for 32, because same member of our staff not have 64 bit pc.

The code for compile 64 bit is this >

```
@echo off

set CURR=%~dp0

set QT_VERSION=5.12.1

echo Qt version %QT_VERSION%

rem working dir
set BUILD_DIR=%CURR%\build_all

set WIN_QT=C:\Qt\%QT_VERSION%\mingw73_64\bin
set WIN_COMPILER_DLLS=C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin
set NSIS_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Bin"

rem subfolder where compiler puts real binaries
rem warning! if this changed somehow, installer.nsi must be modified in 2 places
set WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT=release

rem *************************************************************************************
echo 'Compiling Windows'
rmdir /S /Q %BUILD_DIR%\win64
mkdir %BUILD_DIR%\win64

cd %BUILD_DIR%/win64
%WIN_QT%\qmake.exe CONFIG+=release %CURR%\tracker
%WIN_COMPILER_DLLS%\mingw32-make -j 6

del /S /Q %BUILD_DIR%\win64\%WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT%\*.cpp
del /S /Q %BUILD_DIR%\win64\%WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT%\*.o
del /S /Q %BUILD_DIR%\win64\%WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT%\*.h
del /S /Q %BUILD_DIR%\win64\%WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT%\*.obj
del /S /Q %BUILD_DIR%\win64\%WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT%\*.c

%WIN_QT%\windeployqt.exe ^
    --release ^
    --no-quick-import ^
    --no-translations ^
    %BUILD_DIR%\win64\%WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT%\TimeTracker.exe

copy /Y %CURR%\ssl_win\*.dll %BUILD_DIR%\win64\%WIN_REAL_COMPILER_OUT%

cd %CURR%

del /S /Q TimeTrackerInstaller.exe
%NSIS_DIR%\makensis.exe installer.nsi
```

how i can compile this app for 32 bit ?

Comment: You can replace 64-bit of Qt and other tools to 32-bit.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov qt 5.12.1 not have mingw730_32, what i need to do ?

Comment: Compile?.......

Comment: If you don't find a Qt binaries for your target compiler, you should build Qt by yourself.